# Why is the subtheme_style.css not being called?

Tags: theming

On a Drupal Commerce Kickstart installation, I have created a subtheme of Omega Kickstart, following the [process described here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2057387).

Subtheme is saved to:
public_html/sites/all/new_theme

[image]

I kept only two of the *.css files for customization:

- new_theme_style.css
- new-theme-alpha-default.css

I updated the new_theme.info file as follows:

```
name = New Theme
package = Commerce Kickstart
core = 7.x
screenshot = screenshot.png
base theme = omega_kickstart
```

No changes to the Regions / Theme Settings. Updates to the Optional Stylesheets:
    ; OPTIONAL STYLESHEETS

```
css[new_theme_style.css][name] = New theme global style.
css[new_theme_style.css][description] = This file holds all the globally active custom CSS of Monkey theme.
css[new_theme_style.css][options][weight] = 12
settings[alpha_css][new_theme_style.css] = 'new_theme_style.css'
```

Changes made in new-theme-alpha-default.css are working, but changes made to new_theme_style.css are not showing. When I use "Inspect element" tools, I see that global.css is called instead.

Is this an issue with the weight I am assigning here? I copied the css over from another subtheme that is working. I cannot pinpoint the problem...but know it is likely a noobie mistake.

Thx - keb

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had everything set up correctly, but hadn't toggled "ON" the style sheet.

1. Navigate to: Site settings >> Appearance >> Settings >> Toggle Styles
2. Click "ON" checkbox next to New Theme global style. (all) - new_theme_style.css

I slept on it and woke early in the morning, remembering that not only do you need to enable your theme, you need to turn on the style sheet.

Comment: Sleep surely does help a lot of the times :)